# where to find time complexity of java methods?

Tags: java, time-complexity

I am new to java and learning about various methods from docs.oracle.com but the weird thing is, they didn't mention time complexity of any methods described there, e.g. on this page: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int) 
there are some information about "get()" method but no info about complexity! I don't find an appropriate place to ask where to find info about complexity. Maybe there is such information like cplusplus.com but I don't know about. I searched net and failed. So, please forgive me if this is stupid question.

Comment: "The size, isEmpty, get, set, iterator, and listIterator operations run in constant time. The add operation runs in amortized constant time, that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. All of the other operations run in linear time (roughly speaking).". Try reading the description at the top of the class.

Comment: Note that there is no requirement to give the time complexities of method implementations. You will not typically find them, other than in a few very widely-used classes.

Comment: sorry I didn't notice it. But it still seems there isn't enough space to mention complexity of all the methods at the top of a page. My query was, is there any specific place to read everything about a specific method?

Comment: You should be thinking of the implementation of the class as a whole and not just specific methods.

Comment: @bradimus didn't get you, a particular method has its own complexity of a particular class. can you please elaborate your opinion?

Comment: The complexity of `ArrayList#get`, etc are dependant on the underlying implementation of `List`. As per the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), `ArrayList` is a "Resizable-array implementation" which allows constant time implementation of `List#get`. Compare with [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) which is a "Doubly-linked list implementation of the List".  That forces a linear time complexity on its implementation of `List#get`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the very top of that page it says

> The size, isEmpty, get, set, iterator, and listIterator operations run in constant time. The add operation runs in amortized constant time, that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. All of the other operations run in linear time (roughly speaking). The constant factor is low compared to that for the LinkedList implementation.

Comment: so, I need to read the whole page to know something specific about a particular method?

Comment: @agassaa: presumably it is always at the top. Alternatively, if you read docs for other languages / libraries, an easy way to search for complexities is searching for occurrences of "linear", "constant", "quadratic".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) btw, do you think this question needs to be deleted? as it may not promote productivity?

Comment: @agassaa: this question might be helpful for someone who looks for the same information. Usually (and this case is not an exception) there's no need to delete question.